# SQL - only execute 'and' if a condition is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I only want the 'and' condition to be executed if a condition is true. If false the 'and' condition should be ignored.

```
select *

from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a

where t2.a = 'some value'
and t2.b = 'some value' --execute only if f.e. t1.c = 'some value'
```

Comment: Could you suggest a test data where the order of evaluation would make a difference?

Comment: You mean evaluate, not execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.a = t2.a
WHERE t2.a = 'some value'
  AND ((t2.b = 'some value' AND t1.c = 'some value') OR t1.c <> 'some value')
```